# Error when trying to run an executable of a python file

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, cx-freeze

```
Fatal Python error: (pygame parachute) Segmentation Fault
Traceback (most recent call last):
     File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 1150, in resource_exists
          return get_provider(package_or_requirement).has_resource(resource_name)
     File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 1608, in has_resource
          return self.has(self.fn(self.module_path, resource_name))
     File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 1663, in _has
          "Can't perform this operation for unregistered loader type"
NotImplementedError: Can't perform this operation for unregistered loader type
```

I converted a python game I had made into an executable file. I then went to install the game and then went to run it. When I ran the executable file (which was just installed) it gives me that error in a cmd prompt and then says that the application stops working. Nothing from the actual game runs, it instantly stops working.

I used cx_Freeze to convert it into an executable file. I'm running Python 3.4 and have the correct cx_Freeze installed.

Comment: You probably forgot to include an `__init__.py` file in one of your module directories

Comment: So what would I do to fix this? @wpercy

Answer (score 1):

In the various answers that I see for this kind of error. One of your directories is having a python modules, but it is not a package. So, for anything that you use in cx_Freeze, convert it to package by adding `__init__.py` file.

Comment: > "convert it to package by adding __init__.py file". What do you mean? How would I do this?

Comment: If you have a `directory` with `.py` files inside it. And if that doesn't have `__init__.py` file, add an empty `__init__.py` file to that directory.

Comment: what directories am I looking in?

Comment: Those are your files. `I converted a python game I had made into an executable file.` The files in your python game that you are using `cx_Freeze` to convert.

Comment: I've checked and they all have `__init__.py` in them

Comment: I've looked everywhere, I don't understand where it could missing it @Senthil Kumaran